# Ubuntu bionic Kernel 4.15.0 quadro fx 1800 stopped working with nvidia-340

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 18.04, graphics

My system suddenly stopped showing LightDM login screen and log full of errors
If I remove&purge nvidia drivers and fallback to nouveau - it's working. But without hires settings which I badly need.

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G94GL [Quadro FX 1800]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0f:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:25 memory:e2000000-e2ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

---

```
$ uname -r
4.15.0-43-generic
```

Just tried in grub defaults:

> nvidia-drm.modeset=1

Someone else with that problem?

Additional info:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:03.0/0000:0f:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00000638sv000010DEsd0000062Cbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : G94GL [Quadro FX 1800]
driver   : nvidia-304 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin

$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
Loading new nvidia-340-340.107 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-43-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-43-generic
Done.
nvidia:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia_uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
 - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
 - Installing to /lib/modules/4.15.0-43-generic/updates/dkms/
```

Syslog errors:

```
Jan  1 22:44:30 tvheadend kernel: [  174.314926] caller os_map_kernel_space+0x86/0xb0 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
Jan  1 22:44:31 tvheadend systemd-udevd[7551]: Process '/bin/systemctl stop --no-block nvidia-persistenced' failed with exit code 5.
Jan  1 22:44:31 tvheadend systemd-udevd[7573]: Process '/bin/systemctl start --no-block nvidia-persistenced.service' failed with exit code 5.
Jan  1 22:44:31 tvheadend kernel: [  175.595428] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than pnp 00:07 [mem 0x000d1200-0x000e7fff]
Jan  1 22:44:31 tvheadend kernel: [  175.595570] caller os_map_kernel_space+0x86/0xb0 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd-udevd[7577]: Process '/bin/systemctl stop --no-block nvidia-persistenced' failed with exit code 5.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: lightdm.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 36.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: Stopped Light Display Manager.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: Starting Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: Started Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend lightdm[7642]: Seat type 'xlocal' is deprecated, use 'type=local' instead
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend systemd-udevd[7665]: Process '/bin/systemctl start --no-block nvidia-persistenced.service' failed with exit code 5.
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend kernel: [  177.064251] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than pnp 00:07 [mem 0x000d1200-0x000e7fff]
Jan  1 22:44:33 tvheadend kernel: [  177.064381] caller os_map_kernel_space+0x86/0xb0 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
Jan  1 22:44:34 tvheadend systemd-udevd[7668]: Process '/bin/systemctl stop --no-block nvidia-persistenced' failed with exit code 5.
Jan  1 22:44:34 tvheadend systemd-udevd[7690]: Process '/bin/systemctl start --no-block nvidia-persistenced.service' failed with exit code 5.
Jan  1 22:44:34 tvheadend kernel: [  178.352913] resource sanity check: requesting [mem 0x000c0000-0x000fffff], which spans more than pnp 00:07 [mem 0x000d1200-0x000e7fff]
Jan  1 22:44:34 tvheadend kernel: [  178.353057] caller os_map_kernel_space+0x86/0xb0 [nvidia] mapping multiple BARs
```

I suspecting upgrade of Kernel couse that's I found in `/var/log/apt/history.log`:

```
Start-Date: 2018-12-21  06:15:23
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade
Install: linux-headers-4.15.0-43:amd64 (4.15.0-43.46, automatic), linux-modules-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-43.46, automatic), linux-headers-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-43.46, automatic), linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-43.46, automatic), linux-image-4.15.0-43-generic:amd64 (4.15.0-43.46, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-headers-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.42.44, 4.15.0.43.45), linux-image-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.42.44, 4.15.0.43.45), linux-generic:amd64 (4.15.0.42.44, 4.15.0.43.45)
End-Date: 2018-12-21  06:17:05
```

Comment: With the Nvida drivers installed, can you login as guest?  If so, check the ownership of all the dot files (files whose first character is .) with ls -l and see if any are owned by root (none should be).

Comment: Which dot files? Where?
The screen is blank, can only login at tty's (ctrl+alt+F?).
If remove nvidia-340 and that's fallback to nouveau - screen is back and can login in LightDM screen, but resolution is 800x600.

Comment: Sorry, the command was ls -lA in your home directory to see the files.  From a tty should work too.  Change the ownership back to yourself and your group with sudo chown yourusrname:yourgroup filename

Comment: I dont think that's the problem and no, there isn't ownership errors.

Comment: At the grub menu, if you select the previous kernel, does it work with the nvidia drivers?

Comment: I'm remote user of that system and can't choose another item in GRUB menu yet. Could be done in few days.

Answer (score 0):

So, my resolution:

1.As adviced @ubfan1 I'd booted in 4.15.0-42 kernel with attached TFT display (till now the computer works w/o monitor)

2.Decide to install again nvidia-340

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

3.Rebooted and everything went well

4.Rebooted again and becouse I'd seen dkms process compiled modules for both kernels my choose was first, default 4.15.0-43

Voala, display lighst up, Nvidia drivers was loaded and resolution went to the sky.

So that resolution lead me to, first - posible errors in compile under/for 4.15.0-43 and second - problem could be AND missing attached display.

Comfirm: **Missing attached display IS the problem**....weird :/